How to control the brightness of an LED with a potentiometer?
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile int count = 0;
volatile char valor_adc;

//Timer0 (led que pisca)
void setup_timer0() {
    // Configurar o Timer0 no modo CTC
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);  // Modo CTC
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00);  // Prescaler de 1024

    // Configurar o valor de comparação para o temporizador
    OCR0A = 255;  // Valor máximo para o Timer0

    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);// Habilitar interrupção de comparação do Timer0

    sei();// Habilitar interrupções globais
}
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
    
    count++;// Incrementar o contador de interrupções
    
    if (count >= 31) {  
        PORTD ^= (1 << PD6);// Inverte o estado do LED
        count = 0;  // Da restart ao contador
    }
}
// Inicializar Timer2 para usar OC2B no modo Fast PWM(led do brilho)
void timer2_init(void) {

    DDRD |= (1 << PD3);  // Configurar PD3 como saída

    TCCR2A = (1<<WGM01) | (1<<WGM00);;  // Modo Fast PWM
    
    TCCR2A |= (1 << COM2B1); // Usar OC2B (PD3)

    TCCR2B = (1<<CS21)|(1<<CS20);   // Prescaler de 64
    
    
}

// Inicializar ADC
void adc_init(void) {
    ADMUX = 0b01100101;  // AVcc(5V) como referência e selecionar ADC5
    ADCSRA = 0b10000111; // prescaler = 128, enable ad
}
// Função para ler o valor do ADC do canal selecionado (PC5 = ADC5)
void ler_adc() {
    
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC); // Iniciar a conversão
    
    
    while (ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));// Aguardar até a conversão estar completa
    valor_adc = ADCH;
    
    OCR2B = valor_adc;
}

int main(void) {
    timer2_init();  // Inicializar Timer2(PWM)
    adc_init();
    // Configurar o pino do LED como saída
    DDRD |= (1 << PD6);
    
    // Inicializar o Timer0
    setup_timer0();
    while (1) {
        
        ler_adc();
    }
    return 0;
}

So, this is my code, the assembly I know it's fine, but the code is not working I have the potentiometer connected to the PC5 pin, and the led on the PD6 pin, I'm using an atmega 328p.(by the way I can't use delays)
Does anyone know what it can be?

Have you checked that the values from the ADC are what you expect?

Take a look here https://www.adnbr.co.uk/articles/adc-and-pwm-basics

Try to change volatile char valor_adc1 into volatile uint16_t valor_adc; also the output of a OCR2B is PD3 (OC2B) not PD6.

First the timer2 setup. The output of a OCR2B for timer2 is PD3 not PD6.
PD6 is a output for Timer0.
Also in the ADC setup, from what I can see you are setting the ADLAR bit.
Therefore, you need to change your code:
valor_adc = ADCH;
OCR2B = valor_adc;

Or
OCR2B = ADCH; 


thaks, it worked
